# Check if a Date is in Past

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am getting Values out of a MySQL Table and my Date looks like: `DD.MM`

Now I want to check if this Date is in the past. I tried it with `if($ende < date("d.m"));` but it deleted values like **01.11** at the **23.10**.

I need to remove entries that are in the past.

My Code Looks like:

```
if($ende < date("d.m")) {
    $sqls = "DELETE FROM hausaufgaben WHERE Ende='$ende';";
    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sqls)){
        echo "<p>Es gab keine älteren Hausaufgaben</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do this at a query level. This would require you to setup the date column as a actual date datatype and you can format the return with whichever flags you wish.

Comment: Provide some sample data for `hausaufgaben` table. Please refer this link for framing the question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308

Comment: @HarveyFletcher Its an VARCHAR with the Value of DD.MM (f. ex. 23.10)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Fach, "DEU" | HA, "EX" |  Ende "23.10"

Comment: @mnjg123 What if the date is from previous year, eg: `25.12` (will that be deleted or not); but there is no way to identify whether it is previous year or not.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya There will never be any Date from Past Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the date so that it is in two parts, then compare the day and month seperately

```
$ende = "01.11";

$ende_split = explode( '.', $ende );
$ende_tag   = $ende_split[0];
$ende_monat = $ende_split[1];

if( ($ende_tag < date('d')) && ($ende_monat <= date('m')) ){
    $sqls = "DELETE FROM hausaufgaben WHERE Ende='$ende';";

    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sqls)){
        echo "<p>Es gab keine älteren Hausaufgaben</p>";
    }
}
```

monat uses `<=` because the month can be the same, but the day can be in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [`Str_To_Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, to convert your **DD.MM** format string to [MySQL Date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) (**YYYY-MM-DD**).

Since you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990881/check-if-a-date-is-in-past/52991257#comment92887420_52990881) that there will be data only from the current year; I can safely assume that the year is 2018 (It can be made generic by using `YEAR(CURDATE())`.

Try the following query instead:

```
DELETE FROM hausaufgaben 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Ende, '.', YEAR(CURDATE())), 
                  '%d.%m.%Y') < CURDATE()
```

**Additional Details:**

- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%m`     Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- `%Y`     Year as a numeric, 4-digit value